# Jquery script to call Servlet - can't get corret URL of Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, css, servlets

Below, there is jquery script which calls servlet by URL.

I have 2 separate projects.

First is Dynamic Web Project which contains servlets etc.

Second is simple Ratchet HTML-CSS-JS Project which of course contains some pages, scripts and css.

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {                        // When the HTML DOM is ready loading, then execute the following function...
                $('#button').click(function() {               // Locate HTML DOM element with ID "somebutton" and assign the following function to its "click" event...
                    $.get('http://localhost:8080/testuje/text', function(responseText) { // Execute Ajax GET request on URL of "someservlet" and execute the following function with Ajax response text...
                        $('#div').text(responseText);         // Locate HTML DOM element with ID "somediv" and set its text content with the response text.
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Here is my Servlet code:

```
package pl.javastart.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
@WebServlet("/text")
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String text = "some text";

        response.setContentType("text/plain");  // Set content type of the response so that jQuery knows what it can expect.
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // You want world domination, huh?
        response.getWriter().write(text);
        // Write response body.
    }
}
```

The problem is, what should I put in `$.get('http://localhost:8080/testuje/text', function(responseText)` to get servlet content after button click.

Comment: Does the servlet respond when you paste `http://localhost:8080/testuje/text` straight in browser's address bar? If so, then tell the full URL of the page containing that jQuery Ajax code attempting to reach that URL. Most likely this is just a CORS issue.

Comment: can you post your web console output? looks like the cross-domain / cross- origin problem.

Comment: maybe dumb question by me, but have you tried `$.get('http://localhost:8080/text'` without the testuje part?